# Applying a function within the select clause

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a query (longish with joins etc) and for certain fields in the select clause (all of which are of type `decimal?`), I want to return `null` when the DB has them stored as `0`. Doing the following work correctly:

```
var q =
    from O in ....
    ....
    select new
    {
        ...
        Spot = O.Spot == 0 ? null : O.Spot,
        Moneyness = O.Strike / (O.Spot == 0 ? null : O.Spot),
        Volatility = O.Rate == 0 ? null : O.Rate
    };
```

But I would prefer to encapsulate that check for `0` in a function. So I tried

```
private static decimal? NullIfZero(decimal? obj)
{
    return  obj == 0 ? null : obj;
}
```

and then

```
var q =
    from O in ....
    ....
    select new
    {
        ...
        Spot = NullIfZero(O.Spot),
        Moneyness = O.Strike / NullIfZero(O.Spot),
        Volatility = NullIfZero(O.Rate)
    };
```

But now I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not translate expression
>   'NullIfZero(<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.O.Spot)' into SQL and could
>   not treat it as a local expression.

I do NOT get the error if I just try

```
var q =
    from O in ....
    ....
    select new
    {
        ...
        Spot = NullIfZero(O.Spot),
        Moneyness = O.Strike / (O.Spot == 0 ? null : O.Spot),
        Volatility = NullIfZero(O.Rate)
    };
```

But I can't see what the difference between `NullIfZero(O.Spot)` and `(O.Spot == 0 ? null : O.Spot)` is, especially when it only seems to have an effect when use as the divisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query fails because L2S can't translate the function call `NullIfZero`. The second query works because L2S can evaluate local functions if they are part of the last `Select` in the query. This is a very nice feature that EF lacks right now.

Solutions:

1. Inline the function.
2. Try `AsExpandable` from the predicate builder library.

Comment: "The second query works because L2S can evaluate local functions if they are part of the last Select in the query" Can you please explain this further, I don't fully understand what it means...

Comment: You can call any local function in the final select of any L2S query. That function is not translated to SQL. Instead, L2S fetches it's arguments from the store (efficiently) and calls that function as part of object materialization. This feature only works on the final select because you can't just call a location function from T-SQL. L2S factors that function call out of the query that it executes and calls it as a post-processing step.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase, what do you mean by "the final select" and why in my example is `Spot = NullIfZero(O.Spot),` classified as part of the final select yet `Moneyness = O.Strike / NullIfZero(O.Spot),` is not?

Comment: I overlooked that aspect of the question. That is a L2S limitation. This "final select" feature only works for query patterns that it can understand. LINQ support is not total in the sense that there are always patterns that do not work. The set of patterns that work is not documented or defined. It is whatever the L2S implementation gives you. It is expected that you sometimes have to "jiggle" the query a little to make it work. With AsExpandable is always works. I wish they would opensource L2S so that the community can fix bugs.

Comment: OK thanks, so basically I shouldn't worry about this and just work around it?

Comment: Right, as always with LINQ ORMs... Maybe you should switch to EF anyway since L2S is dead. Then you can't use this trick in any way. If you use it now you make migration harder. I'm stuck with L2S for a 100kLOC codebase because of this exact issue.

Comment: See https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4560538-vastly-improve-linq-translation and vote! Note, that you can send multiple votes by clearing cookies or using an incognito window.

Comment: OK thanks for the tip, I won't use the trick then just in case I ever do migrate this. I didn't realise that EF was intended to completely replace L2S. To be honest, up until now I've just been writing out SQL queries as strings with parameters. I have found the getting started docs / tutorials for both EF and L2S quite unintuitive :(

Comment: Then look for different tutorials. L2S is dead easy to get started with. You learn additional things as you go. Better switch to EF asap, though.

Comment: I just was surprised that I had to type out a whole object to match my DB table myself. I thought VS would have some tool that could import that out of the DB schema. I will give EF a proper look again for my next project. Thanks

Comment: There are such tools. Right now I use the designer to generate everything and I customize nothing.